# Create parent node and parent id

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, hierarchy, recursive

I have a table which contains `id`, `nodeid`, `nodevalue`, and `nodelevel` columns.
Now I want to create new temp column `ParentnodeId`.

I tried using CTE but not getting the correct result.

```
Id  Nodeid  NodeLevel   Nodevalue               ParentId
1   100     1           nodevalue1              0
2   200     2           nodevalue2              1
3   300     3           nodevalue3              2
4   400     4           nodevalue4              3
5   500     5           nodevalue5              4
6   600     6           nodevalue6              5
7   700     6           nodevalue7              5
8   800     5           nodevalue8              4
9   900     6           nodevalue9              5
10  1000    5           nodevalue10             4
11  1100    6           nodevalue11             5
12  1200    6           nodevalue12             5
13  1300    6           nodevalue13             5
14  1400    6           nodevalue14             5
15  1500    6           nodevalue15             5
16  1600    5           nodevalue16             4
17  1700    6           nodevalue17             5
18  1800    6           nodevalue18             5
19  1900    7           nodevalue19             6
20  2000    7           nodevalue20             6
21  2100    8           nodevalue21             7
22  2200    9           nodevalue22             8
23  2300    9           nodevalue23             8
24  2400    9           nodevalue24             8
25  2500    7           nodevalue25             6
```

```
with parentId as (
    select
      Id,
      Nodeid,
      NodeLevel,
      Nodevalue,
      NodeLevel - 1 as ParentId
    from table1)

, parentnode as (
    select
      Id,
      Nodeid,
      NodeLevel,
      Nodevalue,
      ParentId,
      CAST(NULL as nvarchar(50))as ParentNode
    from parentId as pId
    where NodeLevel = 1
    union all
    select
      pId1.Id,
      pId1.Nodeid,
      pId1.NodeLevel,
      pId1.Nodevalue,
      pId1.ParentId,
      CAST(pn.MruHierarchyNode as nvarchar(50))as ParentNode
    from parentId as pId1
    inner join parentnode as pn on pn.Id = pId1.ParentId)

select * from parentnode
order by Nodeid
```

I can understand that I wrongly created `ParentId` column using (`nodelevel-1`) and that's the issue in the recursive part inner join.

Could anyone help me to get the correct `Parentid` and `ParentNode`?

The parent should be the row where:

- the `nodeLevel` is the current row's `nodeLevel - 1`
- the `Id` is the highest `Id` that's less than the current row's `Id`

For example the id 9 should have the parent id as 8 (if you check the node level) and id 11 to 15 should have the parent id as 10.

sqlfiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5db43/1)

Comment: What are your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the SQLFiddle supplied by the OP, and interpreting his comments to mean that the parent of a given is the row where the `nodeLevel` is one less than the current row's `nodeLevel`, and where the `Id` is the highest `Id` that's still less than the current row's `Id`, I simply modified the query to get the `ParentId` so it followed those rules:

```
with parentId as (
    select
      Id,
      Nodeid,
      NodeLevel,
      Nodevalue,
      p.ParentId
    from table1 c
           CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(Id) as ParentId
                          FROM table1
                         WHERE nodeLevel = c.nodeLevel - 1
                           AND Id < c.Id
                       ) p
    )
```

The results show that the row with `Id` 9 does indeed have 8 as its parent, and rows where `Id` = 11 - 16 do indeed have 10 as their parent.

Here's the modified [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5db43/11/0)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!
It works correctly!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are just attempting to get the lowest Id for the higher parent node you can use the following (note the use of `group by` and `min` here, this is so that you don't end up with 85 rows of data caused by multiple rows meeting the join criteria).

Test data:

```
DECLARE @Nodes TABLE (Id INT, Nodeid INT, NodeLevel INT, NodeValue VARCHAR(25));
INSERT INTO @Nodes
        ( Id ,
          Nodeid ,
          NodeLevel ,
          NodeValue 
        )
VALUES 
(1,100,1,'nodevalue1'),
(2,200,2,'nodevalue2'),
(3,300,3,'nodevalue3'),
(4,400,4,'nodevalue4'),
(5,500,5,'nodevalue5'),
(6,600,6,'nodevalue6'),
(7,700,6,'nodevalue7'),
(8,800,5,'nodevalue8'),
(9,900,6,'nodevalue9'),
(10,1000,5,'nodevalue10'),
(11,1100,6,'nodevalue11'),
(12,1200,6,'nodevalue12'),
(13,1300,6,'nodevalue13'),
(14,1400,6,'nodevalue14'),
(15,1500,6,'nodevalue15'),
(16,1600,5,'nodevalue16'),
(17,1700,6,'nodevalue17'),
(18,1800,6,'nodevalue18'),
(19,1900,7,'nodevalue19'),
(20,2000,7,'nodevalue20'),
(21,2100,8,'nodevalue21'),
(22,2200,9,'nodevalue22'),
(23,2300,9,'nodevalue23'),
(24,2400,9,'nodevalue24'),
(25,2500,7,'nodevalue25')
```

The query:

```
SELECT n1.Id ,
       n1.Nodeid ,
       n1.NodeLevel ,
       n1.NodeValue, 
       ISNULL(MIN(n2.Id), 0) AS ParentNodeId
FROM @Nodes n1
    LEFT JOIN @Nodes n2 ON n1.NodeLevel -1 = n2.NodeLevel
GROUP BY n1.Id ,
         n1.Nodeid ,
         n1.NodeLevel ,
         n1.NodeValue
```

Comment: Assumes all rows at `nodeLevel` 6 are children of the first row at `nodeLevel` 5. Which is possible, but seems somewhat unlikely....

Comment: Agreed, but there is no other way to interpret the data based on what OP provided, other than to return all potential matches which blows out the data set.

Comment: Hence my asking for the rule to be used to identify a parent. That said, I'd actually guess that the parent would probably be the row with the highest ID value (less than the child's ID value) where `parent.nodeLevel = child.nodeLevel - 1`

Comment: ...which is, of course, a fairly horrible way to do things in the real world. Of course, this may not be a real world example....

Comment: @RDFozz It would be pretty easy to change to get the most recent node by changing it to MAX(n2.Id) and add to the ON clause n1.id > n2.id

Answer (score 0):

I've used data supplied on your question.

> ```
> create table foo (Id int, Nodeid int,  NodeLevel int,  Nodevalue varchar(100));
> insert into foo (id, nodeid, nodelevel, nodevalue) values
> (1,   100,  1, 'nodevalue1'),--0
> (2,   200,  2, 'nodevalue2'),--1
> (3,   300,  3, 'nodevalue3'),--2
> (4,   400,  4, 'nodevalue4'),--3
> (5,   500,  5, 'nodevalue5'),--4
> (6,   600,  6, 'nodevalue6'),--5
> (7,   700,  6, 'nodevalue7'),--5
> (8,   800,  5, 'nodevalue8'),--4
> (9,   900,  6, 'nodevalue9'),--5
> (10,  1000, 5, 'nodevalue10'),--4
> (11,  1100, 6, 'nodevalue11'),--5
> (12,  1200, 6, 'nodevalue12'),--5
> (13,  1300, 6, 'nodevalue13'),--5
> (14,  1400, 6, 'nodevalue14'),--5
> (15,  1500, 6, 'nodevalue15'),--5
> (16,  1600, 5, 'nodevalue16'),--4
> (17,  1700, 6, 'nodevalue17'),--5
> (18,  1800, 6, 'nodevalue18'),--5
> (19,  1900, 7, 'nodevalue19'),--6
> (20,  2000, 7, 'nodevalue20'),--6
> (21,  2100, 8, 'nodevalue21'),--7
> (22,  2200, 9, 'nodevalue22'),--8
> (23,  2300, 9, 'nodevalue23'),--8
> (24,  2400, 9, 'nodevalue24'),--8
> (25,  2500, 7, 'nodevalue25');--6
> ```

Then I've added a new column called ParentId.

> ```
> ALTER TABLE foo ADD ParentId int NULL;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE foo
> SET    ParentId = NodeLevel -1;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 25 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM foo;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Nodeid | NodeLevel | Nodevalue   | ParentId
> -: | -----: | --------: | :---------- | -------:
>  1 |    100 |         1 | nodevalue1  |        0
>  2 |    200 |         2 | nodevalue2  |        1
>  3 |    300 |         3 | nodevalue3  |        2
>  4 |    400 |         4 | nodevalue4  |        3
>  5 |    500 |         5 | nodevalue5  |        4
>  6 |    600 |         6 | nodevalue6  |        5
>  7 |    700 |         6 | nodevalue7  |        5
>  8 |    800 |         5 | nodevalue8  |        4
>  9 |    900 |         6 | nodevalue9  |        5
> 10 |   1000 |         5 | nodevalue10 |        4
> 11 |   1100 |         6 | nodevalue11 |        5
> 12 |   1200 |         6 | nodevalue12 |        5
> 13 |   1300 |         6 | nodevalue13 |        5
> 14 |   1400 |         6 | nodevalue14 |        5
> 15 |   1500 |         6 | nodevalue15 |        5
> 16 |   1600 |         5 | nodevalue16 |        4
> 17 |   1700 |         6 | nodevalue17 |        5
> 18 |   1800 |         6 | nodevalue18 |        5
> 19 |   1900 |         7 | nodevalue19 |        6
> 20 |   2000 |         7 | nodevalue20 |        6
> 21 |   2100 |         8 | nodevalue21 |        7
> 22 |   2200 |         9 | nodevalue22 |        8
> 23 |   2300 |         9 | nodevalue23 |        8
> 24 |   2400 |         9 | nodevalue24 |        8
> 25 |   2500 |         7 | nodevalue25 |        6
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a9b6a41f1a08a79d7025811cda180231)*

Comment: Here the parent ids are wrong and I want to create parent id using the Id column. For example the id 9 should have the parent id as 8 and id 11 to 16 should have the parent id as 10 but here for id 9, the parent id is 5 and for id 11 to 15, the parent id is also 5 which is wrong.